# Empty Grid When Loading Google Maps and Foursquare

Tags: android, google-maps, foursquare

I have been trying to compile the program on this website and got most of it working. The problem is that when google maps loads, all I get is an empty grid. Is anyone who is familiar with this open source code know why this is the case?

Here is the website:

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/09/05/integrate-foursquare-android-application/

Here is the link to the source code:

https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidFoursquareGoogleApiJavaClient

Best,

Aneem

EDIT, Here is how I create the Geopoint:

```
GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(43, -73);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks Like you haven't get a api key for your signing key, to get a map api key please follow below link:

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Answer (score 0):

You are just showing the map, show it is showing empty grids, once you add Location(lat,long) it will start showing map.

Comment: This code actually uses Geopoint instead of Location. And I do give it values, ill post the line up above. It is still an empty grid.